# Using mysqli_ functions with mysql_ connection?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have written some code that is using `mysqli_` a lot. The problem is that I now need to integrate this code with code that is using `mysql_`, and takes care of connection, authentication etc. I don't want to create a second connection, but `mysql_` lacks a few features, for example, prepared queries. So I'd like to somehow magically "import" the connection into `mysqli`. Is this even possible? If so, how can that be done?

Comment: Couldn't you just create a `mysqli_connect` connection?

Comment: @F4r-20, I don't quite have access to authentication information and besides, I don't like the idea of using two connections at once for no reason. But since I'm currently looking for a quick fix to integrate my code (and hopefully do it right later), I'm certainly considering this option ))

Comment: What you should do is get rid of all the `mysql_` calls. If this project is to be maintained you're going to have to do it sooner than later anyway. Might as well do it now.

Comment: @JanHančič, there are more important things right now. Besides, I don't feel like it's appropriate for me to make calls like that yet... But I do hope that we'll get there eventually )

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's impossible.

By the way, prepared statements is not the only way to make queries safe.
It's *placeholders* that everyone should use, and they not necessarily have to be implemented using prepared statements.
While placeholders can be easily implemented using mysql_* functions as well

Comment: Security is not the only reason to use `mysqli`. The other is performance: prepared statements can be cached, and so do not need to go through parsing, optimization and other stuff that MySQL does internally to your queries. If you just escape all of the strings in the query, it's fairly safe, but then for MySQL it's a new query every time, so it's a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

A connection resource created by `mysql_connect` can't by reused with the MySQLi extension. You will either have to handle the connection in your current code or refactor the old code.

This is not as hard as it may sound. MySQLi also has a procedural interface and you can use the extension just like you do with the old MySQL extension.
The biggest benefit of MySQLi is the object oriented interface which would make refactoring a bit more complicated. MySQLi natively also supports (wraps into methods/functions) MySQL features like prepared statements, transactions and connection charset, but this doesn't mean you can't submit a `START TRANSACTION` or `SET CHARSET utf8` just like you did with `mysql_query`

Hope this helps. If you have more specific questions regarding the refactoring feel free to ask :)

Answer (score -1):

As F4r-20 pointed out, you could just change the way you connect to the database and replace the `mysql_` functions with `msqli_` ones!

Try to decide what you are going to use BEFORE you start a project, not in the middle. Preparing saves a lot of time and issues like this.

---

PS. I would use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) next time. It is easy, fast, OOP and supports multiple database types!

---

**Edit:** since you don't have access to the credentials or how you connect to the database, you will have to use `mysql_`, change the connection to `mysqli_` or make a new connection... Sorry :(

Comment: AfterEdit: To be honest it's going to have to be changed at some point maybe the OP should suggest to those who have access to get it done now.